# C#: JWT bearer token authentication failure: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, jwt, pfx, p12

I'm encrypting JWT with a cert on the client-side and trying to validate that JWT on the server-side but it is always failing. Can anyone please help?

**Sender**

```
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
 var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
       Audience = "https://you.com",
       Issuer = "https://me.com",
       Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new List < Claim > { new Claim("sub", "MyName")),
       IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
       Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(50),
       EncryptingCredentials = new X509EncryptingCredentials(new X509Certificate2("certificate.crt", "XYZ"))
       };

var JWT = handler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor);
```

Tested the above JWT token to check if the cert and pfx file are correct.

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var claimsPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(
    token,
    new TokenValidationParameters
    {
       ValidAudience = "https://you.com",
       ValidIssuer = "https://me.com",
       RequireSignedTokens = false,
       TokenDecryptionKey = new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx", "XYZ"))
    },
    out SecurityToken securityToken);
```

`securityToken` has all the info passed in the JWT token. So I know that there is no issue with cert or pfx file

Passing the JWT token ("`Bearer {token}`") in my rest call as header

**Receiver**

```
[HttpPut("Authenticate"), Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Auth([FromBody] User user)
{
    // stuff
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  //...
  X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx", "XYZ");
  SecurityKey key = new X509SecurityKey(cert);
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
      options.Authority = "https://me.com";
      options.Audience = "https://you.com";
      options.SaveToken = true;
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
          ValidIssuer = "https://me.com",
          ValidAudience = "https://you.com",
          IssuerSigningKey = key
      };
    });
}
```

In the rest call, I'm always getting 401: Unauthorized error. The cert and pfx files seem fine. Am I doing something wrong on the client-side or do I need to do anything else on client side to authorize the JWT ?

Comment: Anyone? Any ideas/suggestions/recommendations? :(

Comment: Why are you using a `PUT` instead of `POST` when authenticating? Did you try that?

Comment: Yeah. same result for put/post.

Comment: I see. You mention you're encrypting the cert client-side, but it's in fact server-side. A client should consume and use JWT. Nothing else. 
Try using a SecretKey from appsettings instead? Maybe that will help isolate your issue. 

I don't think you need to decorate your controller endpoints the `Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes)`. This in Startup should suffice:
`serviceCollection.AddAuthentication(o=>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})`

Comment: Wrong verbiage with client/server, maybe sender/receiver are the right words. Secret key works but I need a public/private key so using p12/pfx file.

Comment: You might be missing some setup stuff to use a cert. Do you check this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0